# Where to search for the executed code from get_template_parts?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

The WP theme I am working on uses `get_template_part('foobar');` a lot in various places. Where should I search for the block's code? Is it in functions.php or in other files?

Comment: what you mean by  block's code ?

Comment: Sorry for that stupid question

Answer (score 2):

`get_template_part('foobar');` is same as `require 'foobar.php';`. So you have a file named as `foobar.php` in your theme root directory.

See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9978/how-to-use-get-template-part

Comment: omg, missed the 'filename' completely. Thanks for the enlightening.